# xcode the signature was invalid contains disallowed entitlements Error in ios

Tags: ios, xcode4.6, provisioning-profile

I am developing since 2 years ios Projects few are uploaded to app store.

But today I found new error while uploading app with xcode4.6.2. I have searched a lot.!
Also I realesed 1st version version of product in iTunes.

[image]

please help me to sove this problem.
And

1. I Revoke  distributed cert. Delete provision.
2. create new distributed certificate and using it generate new provision,
3. I can see that cert in my keychain aceess.
4. also able to get provision on xcode with labeled Valid Profile.
5. The app build sucessfull without any error.

But still same error I found while uploading app on to appStore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved issue... I have submitted the app from origin machine where the project was created... I don't know whether it is right ans or not.. But It works for me...

Answer (score 0):

Don't revoke your certificate. generate a new certificate(distributed).
generate a new provisioning profile(distributed) using that certificate.
Remove existing provisioning profile from organiser.
Download and install certificate and provisioning profile again.
Sign your code with new provisioning profile.
Clean and build your project.
Achieve it for app store.

Comment: Thanks for reply.. Done this yesterday after your reply.. But still same error.